# getting similarity score in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

How can I get similarity score between the query and each of retrieved documents in Solr?

Furthermore, how can I set Solr retrieval method? 
For example, chose between Vector Space model or Document Language Model.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you mentioned in your own answer, you can specify Solr you want to retrieve the score of every document using `fl=*, score`. You can see it reading [this documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_see_the_relevancy_scores_for_search_results)

First of all, Lucene/Solr, only provides [TF-IDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) (VSM based) scoring strategy. If you decided to plug-in third party Similarity implementations, you [can change the scoring strategy](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Similarity) used by Solr, but you can't change it in query basis. In fact, you need to [reload the core](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin#RELOAD) to change it.

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9262300/1593370 
you can add score field to the result by adding `fl=*,score` to your request.

but I still cant  find a way to chose the retrieval method.